# setInterval for stopwatch

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I'm trying to make a stopwatch. Here's the code:

```js
var min = 0, sec = 0, censec = 0

$("#startBtn").on("click", function() { // when start button is clicked
 $(this).hide();   // start is hidden
 $("#stopBtn").show();  // stop is shown
 setInterval(add, 10);  // the censec will be increased every 10 millisecond.
 $("#censec").text(censec);
})

function add() {
 censec++;
 if (censec == 100) {
  censec = 0;
  sec++;        
  if (sec == 60) {
   sec = 0;
   min++;
  }
 }    
}
```

The problem is that `setInterval()` happens only at once. The `censec` only changes from `00` to `1`. That's it.

P.S. I'm new to coding, so if there are other mistakes, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Besides my answer you can also check the Greeter example that MS uses for Typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval` calls to `add` will definitely repeat. But your code is only ever *showing* the value of `censec` once, when you *start* the timer.

If you want to update the display every hundredth of a second, put the code showing the value *in* `add`.

Separately, the code as it is in the question won't run at all, because it has a `ReferenceError` on the first line. Those `;` should be `,`.

Example (this also stores the timer's handle and clears the timer when you click the stop button):

```js
var min = 0, sec = 0, censec = 0;
// Note ---^--------^

function add() {
  censec++;
  if (censec == 100) {
    censec = 0;
    sec++;        
    if (sec == 60) {
      sec = 0;
      min++;
    }
  }    
  $("#censec").text(censec);
}

var timer = 0;

$("#startBtn").on("click", function() { //when start button is clicked
  $(this).hide();        //start is hidden
  $("#stopBtn").show();  //stop is shown
  timer = setInterval(add,10);   //the censec will be increased every 10 millisecond.
});
$("#stopBtn").on("click", function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = 0;
  $(this).hide();
  $("#startBtn").show();
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="startBtn" value="Start">
<input type="button" id="stopBtn" value="Stop" style="display: none">
<div id="censec"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that although it may be mostly fine to use `setInterval` for displaying, using it to *track* the elapsed time is a bad idea; it frequently doesn't fire precisely.

Instead, record when you started

```
var start = Date.now();
```

...and then when the timer fires, figure out how long it's been since you started

```
var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
```

Then use the value (milliseconds) in `elapsed` to figure out your display.

Comment: The first line was a mistake while writing this question, it was fine in the original code. Can't setInterval be used without clearInterval? If possible, explain the code involving timer. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @eknoor4197: Yes, `setInterval` can be used without `clearInterval`: The timer will never stop firing. But you had a "stop" button so I assumed you wanted it to be able to stop. Re the `timer` code: I think it's pretty well explained above. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval).

Answer (score 0):

Your variable declarations have ; instead of , .

Also checking numbers on equality should be done by using === but that is not the problem here.

Your also not updating the view in your timer. So updating of your html should also be in your function that is called by the timer.

If the goal is to use real seconds and milliseconds, I also suggest using the Date type because your timer will be late and not real-time. So still use the timer with the interval you like but in the add function you call the date object. You can replace the 3 vars for one datetime of type Date which will give you the granularity that you like.

```
var dateTimeStart = null, censecElement = null, timer = null;

$("#startBtn").on("click", function() {//when start button is clicked
    $(this).hide();        // start is hidden
    $("#stopBtn").show();  // stop is shown
    if(timer === null) {
        // timer was not started 
        dateTimeStart = new Date();
        timer = setInterval(updateCensec, 10);   //the censec will be increased every 10 millisecond.
        console.log("Started timer");
    }
});

$("#stopBtn").on("click", function() {//when stop button is clicked
    $(this).hide();        // stop is hidden
    $("#startBtn").show();  // start is shown
    if(timer) {
        // timer is started/running
        clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("Stopped timer");
    }
    timer = null;
});

function updateCensec() {
    var sensec = 0, sec = 0, dateTimeNow = new Date(), diffMilliseconds = 0;
    diffMilliseconds = dateTimeNow - dateTimeStart;
    censec = parseInt((diffMilliseconds % 600 ) / 10); // convert milliseconds to centi seconds
    sec = parseInt(diffMilliseconds / 600);
    if(censecElement === null) {
        censecElement = $("#censec");
    }
    censecElement.text(sec + ":" + censec);
}
```

I would like to suggest that you do not update your view every 10 milliseconds even if you want your stopwatch to show time in centiseconds.